# How to pass an event to as an arg in a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-handling, arguments

I am trying to have a event handler that when the DOM is clicked, it calls some function. That function will have an argument that it's value will be the event.

```
$playlist.on('click tap', changeTrack(e))
```

Obviously this does not work. it works if I dont pass the arguments like `$playlist.on('click tap', changeTrack` but how can I pass the event?

The only reason I need the event is for getting an ID name. such as `e.target.id`.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$playlist.on('click tap', changeTrack)` does pass the event to `changeTrack`. In the implementation `changeTrack(ev) { /* ev is the event passed from the event dispatch */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything other than set up the event callback. The event will automatically be passed to that callback for you. You just have to access it:

```js
$(document).on("click", callback);

function callback(evt){
  console.log(evt.target.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">Click me</p>
<div id="d1">Click me</div>
<a id="a1" href="#" >Click me</a>
```